# How do I select a column name into a variable rather than the content of the column?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am looping through a bunch of columns (all beginning with RUA6) and for the one (there will always be exactly one) that has the value 'R' I want to set the name of this column as another variable. I'm doing the following but I don't know how to grab the name of the column and not the value.

```sql
DECLARE @RUA6isRef varchar(255)
DECLARE @RUA6vars varchar(255)

DECLARE crsTo CURSOR
FOR

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VenUS6_M0Inv'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'RUA6%'

OPEN crsTo

FETCH NEXT FROM crsTo
INTO @RUA6vars

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @RUA6vars = 'R' SELECT @RUA6isRef = @RUA6vars

FETCH NEXT FROM crsTo
INTO @RUA6vars

END

CLOSE crsTo
DEALLOCATE crsTo
```

Comment: `@RUA6vars` will have the name of the column already, not the "value". A column can have *many* values, as there will be many rows. What are you actually trying to achieve here? The fact you want to do something like this infers a design flaw as well.

Comment: This will only be dealing with one row so only one value per column. I want to save into the variable @RUA6vars the name of the column that contains the value 'R'. There will only be one of them.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. What I want to do is once I have identified which of the columns contains the value 'R' I then need to run a separate bit of code, so I need to grab the values of all the columns being looped through, check which one = 'R' and then save this column name in the @RUA6vars variable

Comment: Problem solved: